# Recursive method, load children. Java

Tags: java

I have an entity that has an attribute "father" is a reference to his father. (Like this in the database)
Now I need to create a tree in view, and I have to carry the children recursively.
I have made the method below, but I doubled the children. And not further if the (optimal) correct way to do this process.
Can somebody help me.
Thank you.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true) 
public Page<CategoriaDTO> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("Request to get all Categorias");
    Page<Categoria> result = categoriaRepository.findByPadreIsNull(pageable);
    List<CategoriaDTO> categoriaDtos = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Categoria categoriaAux : result) {
        CategoriaDTO categoriaDto = categoriaMapper.categoriaToCategoriaDTO(categoriaAux);
        categoriaDto.setHijos(categoriaMapper.categoriasToCategoriaDTOs(categoriaRepository.findByPadre(categoriaAux)));
        hijos(categoriaDto.getHijos(),categoriaDto.getId());
        categoriaDtos.add(categoriaDto);
    }

    return new PageImpl<CategoriaDTO>(categoriaDtos);
}

private void hijos(List<CategoriaDTO> hijos,Long padreId){
    Categoria categoriaPadre = categoriaRepository.findOne(padreId);
    if(! CollectionUtils.isEmpty(hijos)){
        for (CategoriaDTO hijo : hijos) {
            hijo.setHijos(categoriaMapper.categoriasToCategoriaDTOs(categoriaRepository.findByPadre(categoriaPadre)));
            hijos(hijo.getHijos(),hijo.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, in your entity you have a reference to the same entity.
So you could start the leaf and go up in the tree. Call the function recursively until the Entity has null parent(that means you reached the root). You also add the Entities to a list.

```
LinkedList<Category> list = new LinkedList<>();

public void getChildren(Category category) {
    list.add(category);
    if(category.getParent() == null) 
      return;

    getChildren(category.getParent());
}
```

This is just an example, post your Entity for more details